# XPath regular expression through text

Tags: regex, xml, xpath, text

i have a small problem using regular expression through text.

The part of my XML file looks like this

resipes.xml

```
 <text name="preparation">
   portion= 4 Person 
   time = 20 Minutes
   difficulty = medium
</text>
```

What i want is to search in the text e.g. for "portion" and view just "4 Person"

i´ll be very grateful for any help
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex pattern to find the value of portion:

```
.+portion\s*=\s*(.+)
```

See a [working demo](https://regex101.com/r/sF7pA0/3).

Explanation:

`.+` matches any characters,

`portion` matches the *portion* string,

`\s*=\s*` matches the equals sign including the preceding and following whitespace characters (if there are any),

`(.+)` captures the rest of the characters in the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
normalize-space(
     substring-after(
          substring-before(//text/text(), "time"), 
          "portion="))
```

result

```
String='4 Person'
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a working example:

from lxml import etree

```
class mySearch:
    def __init__(self, fileName):
        self.doc=etree.parse(fileName)
        self.text = self.doc.getroot().text
        self.values = dict()
        lines = self.text.split('\n')
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip() !='':
                entry = line.split('=')[0].strip()
                value = line.split('=')[1].strip()
                self.values[entry] = value

    def search(self, textTerm):
        try:
            return self.values[textTerm]
        except:
            return 'not found'

k = mySearch('data.xml')
print(k.search('time'))
```

where you can put that script at the same directory with an xml file called `data.xml` and the content of that xml is:

```
<text name="preparation">
   portion= 4 Person 
   time = 20 Minutes
   difficulty = medium
</text>
```